# Why ServiceStack.Text doesn't default dates to iso8601?

Tags: .net, json, servicestack, json.net

If I use Newtonsoft.Json.NET it defaults to iso8601 (i.e.: `2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00`) for serializing/deserializing dates.

Why ServiceStack.Text doesn't default to this and I need to specify it as a configuration setting?

Answer (score 35):

ServiceStack followed the .NET DataContractSerializer defaults, not JSON.NET. We are reluctant to make breaking changes like this, especially when there's an easy way to configure it otherwise with:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
```

Comment: What's the easy way to configure it otherwise? :)

Comment: JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;

Comment: **Note:** `JsonDateHandler` has been changed to `DateHandler`.