# What should I be aware of when migrating from Json.NET to ServiceStack.Text

Tags: .net, json, json.net, servicestack

I have an existing REST API with many consumers, that primarily talk JSON. It is built with Json.NET, but we want to migrate to use ServiceStack.Text for serialization. This question is about the serialization part only, not about using ServiceStack to expose the services (I will get to that later).

I know there is likely to be an issue with [the date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882987/why-servicestack-text-doesnt-default-dates-to-iso8601), and I can handle that - but other than that, is there any differences that I need to be aware of ?

Is there an easy way to test that I don't break any clients ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue I have had with ServiceStack.Text that I found JSON.NET could handle is Reference loops. I am happy to be wrong, but I don't think ServiceStack.Text has support for ignoring these loops. (I last tried around the middle of this year, not sure if more recent updates have added support for this or not yet). This issue only arose for me due to how my database was structured, but it can occur.

**EDIT:** And this issue has since been solved. So basically, no, in my experience. Also, the support the ServiceStack and it's modules is pretty amazing, so if you do have a problem, it's likely someone can help.

Comment: While ServiceStack's Serializers didn't support cyclical deps for a long time, it has [since added support them](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/CyclicalDependencyTests.cs). Please submit an issue if you find a use-case that it still doesn't support.