# ServiceStack.Text and ISODate("")

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, servicestack

Why ServiceStack.Text DeserializeFromString cant convert ISODate formats.

For example, i have json string like

```
{ "Count" : 4, "Type" : 1, "Date" : ISODate("2013-04-12T00:00:00Z") }
```

and class

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and when i try to deserialize from string

```
JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<TestClass>(json);
```

give me output like 
[image]

Comment: It probably does not expect `ISODate` word to be there. Try `{ "Count" : 4, "Type" : 1, "Date" : "2013-04-12T00:00:00Z" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON` expects the date format like this

```
"LastRequestTime":"\/Date(928129800000+0530)\/"
```

So change you date value in `Json` string and then try. it will deserialized that property properly.

Comment: JSON has no dateformat, Ecma 6 and 5.1 does! The set ISO8601 as the new default standard.

Answer (score 19):

ServiceStack.Text understands ISO8601, too.

You can configure it as the default behaviour with:

```
JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11887560/6884) for more information.

Comment: JsonDateHandler has been renamed to DateHandler